# Send reminder email every three days after certain date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

This is my first post so apologies in advance for any newbie mistakes. I've tried researching different solutions to this problem and so far haven't come across one that seems to fit my particular case.

I have an app where individuals create `evaluations`, and if the minimum requirements haven't been fulfilled 7 days after the `created_at` date, I want to send reminder emails every 3 days prompting them to take action.

The `reminders.rb` file looks like this, with `Evaluation::ASSESSMENTS_COMPLETION_WAIT_TIME` set to `7.days` and `Reminders::LIMBO_EMAIL_INTERVAL_DAYS` set to `3`:

```
def self.send_peer_shortage_notifications
    time = Time.current - Evaluation::ASSESSMENTS_COMPLETION_WAIT_TIME
    range = time..Time.current
    today = Time.current.to_date

    evaluations = Evaluation.arel_table
    assessments = Assessment.arel_table

    left_join = evaluations
                .join(assessments, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)
                .on(evaluations[:id].eq(assessments[:evaluation_id]),
                    assessments[:state].in([:pending, :complete]),
                    assessments[:assessor_id].not_in([evaluations[:user_id],
                                                      evaluations[:manager_id]]))
                .join_sources

    relation = Evaluation
               .in_process
               .joins(left_join)
               .where(created_at: range)
               .group(:user_id)
               .having(evaluations[:user_id].count.lt(Evaluation::MINIMUM_NUM_PEERS))

    relation.find_each do |evaluation|
      days_in_limbo = (today - (evaluation.created_at + Evaluation::ASSESSMENTS_COMPLETION_WAIT_TIME).to_date).to_i
      if days_in_limbo % Reminders::LIMBO_EMAIL_INTERVAL_DAYS == 0
        EvaluationMailer.delay.limbo_notification(evaluation)
      end
    end
  end
```

My `reminders_rspec.rb` looks like this (the first test fails and I can't figure out why):

```
context 'minimum number of peer assessments not in pending/complete and limbo email interval day' do
      limbo_interval_array = Array.new(10) { |i| i*Reminders::LIMBO_EMAIL_INTERVAL_DAYS }

      let!(:evaluation) { create(:evaluation, created_at: (Evaluation::ASSESSMENTS_COMPLETION_WAIT_TIME + limbo_interval_array.sample.days).ago) }
      let!(:assessments) do
        create_list(:assessment,
        Evaluation::MINIMUM_NUM_PEERS,
        evaluation: evaluation,
        state: [:expired, :declined].sample)
      end

      it 'sends limbo email' do
        expect { subject }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
      end
    end

    context 'on every non-third day since limbo' do
      array = (1..20).to_a
      limbo_interval_array = Array.new(10) { |i| i*Reminders::LIMBO_EMAIL_INTERVAL_DAYS }
      non_limbo_interval_array = array - limbo_interval_array


      let!(:evaluation) { create(:evaluation, created_at: (Evaluation::ASSESSMENTS_COMPLETION_WAIT_TIME + non_limbo_interval_array.sample.days).ago) }
      let!(:assessments) do
        create_list(:assessment,
        Evaluation::MINIMUM_NUM_PEERS,
        evaluation: evaluation,
        state: [:expired, :declined].sample)
      end

      it 'sends nothing' do
        expect { subject }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(0)
      end
    end
```

Is there a simpler way to write and test this? This seems overly complicated for what I"m trying to do but I haven't been able to find a simpler way.

Comment: I see a lot of sh***y first posts. This one seems pretty okay. +1 for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it seems you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. The key here is that you want to use a queuing backend to dispatch your email notifications asynchronously. Since reminders are to be send 7 days after creating an Evaluation, the delayed email would be queued `#create` action of the `EvaluationsController`:

```
class EvaluationsController < ApplicationController

def create
  # Do whatever it is you do to create an evaluation

  if @evaluation.valid?
     EvaluationMailer.delay_for(7.days).limbo_notification(evaluation.id)  # Pass an ID rather than a model object, and use `find_by` within `limbo_notification`
     # redirect or whatever...
  end
end
```

Now, all the hard work is going to be done by your queuing backend `ActiveJob` which will automatically send the email for you after 7 days.

Queueing backend are a big subject and rather than elaborate on how they work, I'll point you to the documentation here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html. For a specific queuing backend I'd recommend Sidekiq with Redis.